# R: can 'mu' or 'Sigma' be vectorized in MASS::mvrnorm() when generating bivariate normal samples?

Tags: r, random, vectorization, normal-distribution

Consider the data below,

```
n <- 3
phi0 <- 1
phi1 <- 0.1
phi2 <- 0.2
W2 <- runif(n,0,1)
W3 <- runif(n,0,1)
W <- cbind(W2,W3)
phi <- rbind(phi0,phi1,phi2)
rho <- 0.4
sigma1 <- exp(as.numeric(model.matrix(~W) %*% phi))
sigma2<- 1

library(MASS)
#Sigma <- ???
mu <- rep(0,2)
v <- mvrnorm(n, mu, Sigma)
```

`sigma1` is my vector of variance.

I want to generate a bivariate vector `v=(v1,v2)` of length `n` with normal bivariate distribution. In such a way that the i-th line of `v` has a bivariate normal distribution of mean `mu=(0,0)`, correlation `rho=0.4` and marginal variance `sigma=(sigma1, 1)` where `sigma1` receives the value of the i-th line `sigma1`. How can I proceed?

---

*Editor's clarification*

In 1D case, `rnorm` accepts vectorized `mu` and `sigma`, so that

```
rnorm(3, 0, sqrt(sigma1))
```

gives samples from `N(0, sqrt(sigma1[i]))`. Basically OP is asking the same capability for `mvrnorm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## basic solution

No, it can't be vectorized. Write a `for` loop.

```
v <- matrix(0, n, 2)
for (i in 1:n) {
  sig11 <- sigma1[i]
  sig21 <- rho * sqrt(sig11)
  Sigma <- matrix(c(sig11, sig21, sig21, 1), 2)
  v[i, ] <- mvrnorm(1, c(0,0), Sigma)
  }
```

## advanced solution

Given a covariance `Sigma`

```
sig11 ^ 2                rho * sig11 * sig22
rho * sig11 * sig22      sig22 ^ 2
```

its lower triangular Cholesky factor `L` is

```
sig11          0
rho * sig22    sqrt(1 - rho ^ 2) * sig22
```

If `x <- rnorm(2)`, then `mu + L %*% x` is a sample from `N(mu, Sigma)`.

This gives a fully vectorized solution

```
# mu1, mu2, sig11, sig22, rho can be
## length-n vectors
## scalars
## vectors than can be recycled to be length-n
birnorm <- function (n, mu1, mu2, sig11, sig22, rho) {
  x1 <- rnorm(n)
  x2 <- rnorm(n)
  z1 <- sig11 * x1 + mu1
  z2 <- rho * sig22 * x1 + sqrt(1 - rho ^ 2) * sig22 * x2 + mu2
  cbind(z1, z2)
  }
```

For your data, you can use

```
v <- birnorm(3, 0, 0, sqrt(sigma1), 1, 0.4)
```

---

## rebuild `mvrnorm` for bivariate case

Note that this function can be used to rebuild `mvrnorm` for bivariate case.

```
mvrnorm2 <- function (n, mu, Sigma) {
  sig11 <- sqrt(Sigma[1])
  sig22 <- sqrt(Sigma[4])
  rho <- Sigma[2] / (sig11 * sig22)
  birnorm(n, mu[1], mu[2], sig11, sig22, rho)
  }
```

and it is faster

```
mu <- c(0,0)
Sigma <- matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1),2)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mvrnorm(1000, mu, Sigma), mvrnorm2(1000, mu, Sigma))
```